# MBR Partition Table not found

Tags: windows-7, boot, partitioning, mbr

Well... I was trying to activate my windows 7, the first program that I used was "MBR Regenerator" that would turn windows back to the trial mode. Ok. The program asked to a restart, and I did it.

But, when restarting, it shows "Partition Table not Found"...

I pickd my windows dvd and used the cmd prompt to call "BootRec.exe /fixmbr", but nothing have changed. So, i pick the dvd again and ran the diskpart>list volume, and my disk was showed up as "RAW".

What can I do?

Comment: Are you sure your disk was MBR to start?  It could have had GPT instead, at which point, I think you may be out of luck.

Comment: I'm not sure, but the HD was purchased and soon installed windows 7 on it, I think it is hard to believe that was in GPT ...

Comment: If the system was a modern system with UEFI instead of BIOS, the default for Windows 7 would have been GPT

Answer (score 0):

If it was GPT, it's conceivable that you can recover the GPT data with a suitable GPT partitioning tool. My own GPT fdisk (aka `gdisk`; http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/) might be able to do the job, for instance. You'd probably have to run it from a Linux emergency disc. You'd then want to use the options to recover data from the primary and/or backup partition tables. See the GPT fdisk Web site's page on GPT repair (http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/repairing.html) for details. If that fails, something like TestDisk (http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) might be able to recover your partitions.